# How to reduce the space between uibarbutton and back button in ios?

Tags: ios8, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem

I am trying to use an image adjacent to back button arrow with some little  space.
i have used the code below ,but this have increased space between arrow and image. can anyone tell me how to reduce this space .

```
    UIButton *button1=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    [button1 setFrame:CGRectMake(-10, 2.0, 200, 42.0)];


    UIBarButtonItem *button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:button1];
    button.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -100, 0, -25); //this didn't worked out as expected ...i used this for reducnig space
     self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = button;

//THis allows to add image  / button to the right of back button
self.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = YES;
```